# Manufacturer vs generic printer PPD

Tags: printing, canon

I'm setting up a new printer on my desktop, and a dialog has opened asking which PPD I want to choose. It says the generic version is recommended, but it also has one from Canon, the manufacturer of my printer. Should I choose the Canon or the generic one? The model is PIXMA MG 6821.

Comment: I don't think I would worry too much about which PPD I chose:  If one doesn't work, try the other.  Since you system is recommending the generic, why not give it a shot?

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to. I can't find a driver for my model.

Comment: Please look at the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are drivers available for your printer from the manufacturer - I would suggest that you try these first.

The drivers for the PIXMA MG 6821 are abailable [here](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mg-series-inkjet/pixma-mg6821/pixma-mg6821/!ut/p/z1/hY_BbsIwEES_pR9g7ZKAS44mFCVVDAIhcH1BVhXCtthEiUGIr8fQXgqCzm00b6QZ0KBAO3OgynjaObMN_kPzlZxm_SxPsZiMojcUcr4oZJzHOOOw_A_QIcYHEgjvV-BJPyyIGpnKCnRt_IaRW-9A1Q05XzYtKHLfX6Vndr_1tN67z8twULZibdlQ2bKfPDToaA2zFe9HnRu3BP13Bc6SVxR8yLNkPMB82rsDFoNuAJJhGkejy5Nf4MnR2qpTITKkXLycAftujKk!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/#drivers_downloads_tab).  You want to download the 'debian archive' format.

[Another post](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/11/05/how-to-install-canon-mg6821-printer-driver-on-ubuntu-15-10-wily-32-64bit-quickstart-scanning-easy-guide/) suggests that you may need to install some packages first, although I am unsure why they have chosen the particular installation method that they did.  *I* would suggest that you should download the driver .deb file to some handy location on your home directories, and open it with 'Ubuntu Software Center'

Comment: Thanks. I was reading that tutorial, I was having a hard time finding the driver.

Comment: It was really not clear in the tutorial where the driver was.  My mother has a PIXMA printer however, and I have a little familiarity with that website.

Comment: It's one of the few manufacturer driver sites I've seen that wasn't horribly laid out. At least the install script was nice and straightforward.